# NightwatchJS capture network traffic / network response

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a ReactJS SPA that I'm testing, specifically I'm testing user signup.

This is a response value from the GET request that my SPA makes when a user has signs up.

```
{"data":{"id":1387,"token":"3f38cfd0-a392-11e7-8d24-130a2af7f20a"}}
```

How can I access the data returned from network requests made from my SPA within NightwatchJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a workaround, by adding code into my React SPA that `console.warn`'s out the token when it's received.

Then I'm using NightwatchJS `getLog` method to access the data. This isn't clean by any means.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan is right.

And here is full demo to capture the XHR traffic:

https://github.com/Bugazelle/nightwatch-capture-network-traffic

#### How it is working

1. Take advantage of the `ajaxListener.js`

   > The js is forked from https://gist.github.com/icodejs/3183154

   This hack will make all the XHR requests as a warn log to console

```
    {
        "type": "response",
        "syncMode": this.syncMode,
        "method": this.method,
        "url": this.url,
        "requestData": this.requestData,
        "readyState": this.readyState,
        "responseText": this.responseText,
        "responseCode": this.status,
        "responseHeader": this.getAllResponseHeaders()
    }
```

2. Then take advantage of Nightwatch API [.getLog](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/getLog.html)

   The [.getLog](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/getLog.html) could capture the console warn logs for us